# How can I deploy a shiny app to Heroku

Tags: heroku, shiny

I have a shiny app and want to deploy it to Heroku. I tried to follow the steps as mentioned in:
https://github.com/btubbs/heroku-buildpack-shiny

I created a git Git repository and put the R files into it. Then, I created an app in heroku and tell Heroku to use a custom buildpack for my app. But, I was not be able to enable Heroku websockets support.
Error is:
Couldn't find that feature.

I can't figure out how to deal with this problem. Is there any other way to deploy the shiny app to Heroku?

Comment: Have you perhaps considered this fork recommended by the author?: https://github.com/virtualstaticvoid/heroku-buildpack-r/tree/cedar-14-chroot

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen https://github.com/virtualstaticvoid/heroku-docker-r?

Check out the [example shiny app](https://github.com/virtualstaticvoid/heroku-docker-r-shiny-app) too. To specify additional dependencies, you can still use `init.R`.

To deploy using Docker, you might have to move your current Heroku app to a container stack. This can be done with the heroku stack:set CLI command:

```
$ heroku stack:set container
```

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://github.com/stevecondylios/r-shiny-on-heroku#tutorial-deploy-your-r-shiny-app-on-the-web-usingheroku)'s a minimal example. Basically:

1. Create `run.R` file with the following

```
library(shiny)
port <- Sys.getenv('PORT')
shiny::runApp(
  appDir = getwd(),
  host = '0.0.0.0',
  port = as.numeric(port)
)
```

2. Commit to git
3. Create a new heroku app with

```
heroku create --buildpack https://github.com/virtualstaticvoid/heroku-buildpack-r.git
git push heroku master
```

That's all there is to it.

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to deploy using Docker. I am not an expert, but it took me a couple of days to deploy an app using this soluation. Many tutorials exist and could bring you to achieving this.